# JMeter console freezes if I set some time in Thread Group scheduler in Non GUI Mode

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, siebel, threadgroup

I have prepared JMeter script for a business process for Siebel application, the problem I am currently facing is that due to Database pooling connections are not supposed to close automatically and if I run test with Non-GUI mode it keeps on running even if scheduled time is completed. I have tried with both Normal and Ultimate Thread group, but it does not write any thing in JMeter report. How Can I schedule my test to run for some specific period of time ?

Comment: Did you set duration in Thread group?

Comment: Yes, duration is already there.